# Can not access mysql docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` to create `mysql` container. 
I get host IP `172.21.0.2`.
But when I connect mysql. I get error:

1. My `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:

   ### Mysql container
       mysql:
         image: mysql:latest
         ports:
          - "3306:3306"
         volumes:
          - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
          MYSQL_USER: test
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: test_pass
   ```
2. Get my host IP  `docker inspect db_mysql_1 | grep IPAddress`

   `"IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",`
3. Access mysql: `mysql -h 172.21.0.2 -P 3306 -u root -proot`.

   `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.21.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

How can I connect to mysql container?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass an extra environment variable when starting the MySQL container `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=<ip>` this will create a root user with permission to login from given IP address. In case where you want to allow login from any IP you can specify `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%`.

This will work only for a newly created containers.

When spinning new container:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

In compose file it would be:

```
version: '2'
services:

  ### Mysql container
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test_pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'  # needs to be enclosed with quotes
```

Comment: Should this still work for Docker version 18.09.1 and "mysql:5.7"? I have just tried it, confirmed that the container has the ENV_VAR correctly set, but I get the same error.

Comment: dark ninja magic

Comment: Hi, when I use the enviroment "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %", I receive the message:  "ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 24", could you help me?

Comment: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%' - The % needs be string enclosed

Comment: If you have a "broken" or misconfigured grant tables in the host `/var/lib/mysql` location, setting `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` is not going to work because that "broken" grant tables is already exists on host. Create another mysql container using docker-compose that mounted to the host data location, enter the container terminal, start mysql with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`, and fix the grant tables using root (without password). In my case, I need to drop the problematic users, re-create and re-grant the privileges. This happened to me when I want to change the authentication method of a user.

Comment: the command line doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This way it worked for me:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case. I deleted the volumes configuration and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
docker exec -it mysql1 mysql -u root -p
update mysql.user set host='%' where user='root' and host = 'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

change  `mysql1` to your container name.

P.S: I'm not using `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 2):

When you connect to a MySQL server, it checks it’s `GRANT` table (the "user" table in the "mysql| database on the MySQL server) against the IP address of the connecting MySQL client machine. If there are **NO MATCHING ENTRIES** in the "host" column in the "user" table in the "mysql" database, **MySQL will IMMEDIATELY CLOSE THE CONNECTION** with `ERROR 1130`.

Check if the client is able to get to port 3306 (the MySQL port) on the database server:

```
telnet 172.21.0.2 3306
Trying ::1...
Connected to 172.21.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

You should log in to the MySQL server, and run "mysql" to check the grants table:

```
# mysql mysql

mysql> SELECT host,user FROM user;
+-----------------+-----------+
| host            | user      |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 172.21.0.5      | root      |
| 172.21.0.4      | root      |
| 127.0.0.1       | root      |
| ::1             | root      |
| localhost       | root      |
```

"root" **is** authorized to connect from several IP addresses, but not from the client IP 172.21.0.1. So, just add GRANT access from that IP:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON root.* TO 'your_db'@'172.21.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then, check your connection.

Comment: You have an error in your grant: `grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'172.21.0.1' identified by 'password';`

Answer (score 0):

When i tried `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST= '%'` i got this error message after `docker-compose up`

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'' at line 1

However, using double-quotes `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST= "%"` resolved the issues surprisingly.

This is final `docker-compose.yml` I used, to spin up a container for mysql db.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
db:
image: mysql:8-oracle
container_name: mysqldb2
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=social-media-database
  - MYSQL_USER=test
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
  - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST= "%"
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
restart: always
```